# mutating, trigger/function may not see it error while using Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am having a table bugs_metadata like
create table bugs_metadata(REPORT_NAME varchar2(10), WHERE_CLAUSE varchar2(100));
insert into bugs_metadata('test','29603754,29605708,29649865');
I am getting "mutating, trigger/function may not see it" error in below trigger on update of WHERE_CLAUSE column in above table:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "c_b_c_b_update" AFTER  
    UPDATE ON bugs_metadata
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
CASE
  WHEN UPDATING('WHERE_CLAUSE') THEN
  IF :NEW.WHERE_CLAUSE is not null THEN 
    insert into bug_data(BUG_NUMBER,SUBJECT)
    select rptno,SUBJECT 
    from rpthead 
    where rptno in (select regexp_substr(:NEW.WHERE_CLAUSE,'[^,]+',1,level) WHERE_CLAUSE  
                    from bugs_metadata t2 
                    connect by regexp_substr(:NEW.WHERE_CLAUSE,'[^,]+',1,level) is not null ) 
      and rptno not in(select bug_number from bug_data);

  END IF;
  END CASE; 
END;
```

Could you please let me know what is wrong here?

Comment: Error message is self-explanatory. Your trigger is on `bugs_metadata` table and also uses that table `INSERT INOT bug_data ... SELECT ... WHERE  ... bugs_metadata`.

Comment: Could you please suggest a way to overcome this and achieve the same functionality.

Comment: You shouldn't form your query by using `bugs_metadata` table on which your're trying to construct a trigger. You can replace `bugs_metadata` with `dual`. So, consider @Littlefoot 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`DUAL` should be used instead of `bugs_metadata`. No problem in doing that because you're just splitting a column into rows, so no need to use the actual table as the value already exists in `:new.where_clause`.

See the `--> right here -->` line, it marks the spot.

```
create or replace trigger c_b_c_b_update 
  after update on bugs_metadata
  for each row 
begin
  case
    when updating('WHERE_CLAUSE') then
      if :new.where_clause is not null then 
         insert into bug_data(bug_number, subject)
           select rptno, subject 
           from rpthead 
           where rptno in (select regexp_substr(:new.where_clause, '[^,]+', 1, level) 
--> right here -->         from dual
                           connect by regexp_substr(:new.where_clause, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
                          ) 
             and rptno not in (select bug_number 
                               from bug_data
                              );
      end if;
  end case; 
end;
```